# OS X 10.11でアセンブリを実行する方法

Tags: assembly

OS X 10.11でアセンブリを実行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
GCCだと普通にアセンブルできるようなのですが(`gcc -o helloworld helloworld.s`でアセンブルできるらしい)
clangではどうすればいいのでしょうか?

---

#### 追記

OS X に`as`というコマンドがあり、それがアセンブルをするためのコマンドらしいということは分かりました

---

#### 追記 2

`as -arch x86_64 -o helloworld helloworld.s`と実行したところ,`helloworld`というファイルが生成されたのですが、その後うまく`ld`ができません。
`ld -macosx_version_min 10.11 helloworld`としてみたのですが、
下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます

```
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.10
ld: warning: object file (helloworld) was built for newer OSX version (10.11) than being linked (10.10)
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for inferred architecture x86_64
```

---

```
# original: http://dustin.schultz.io/blog/2010/11/15/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/

# https://gist.github.com/h2so5/d429d0aec527482f6209

.data
hello_world: .asciz "Hello world!\n"

.text
.globl _main

_main:
mov $0x2000004, %rax
mov $1, %rdi
lea hello_world(%rip), %rsi
mov $14, %rdx
syscall
mov $0x2000001, %rax
mov $0, %rdi
syscall
```

Comment: 別のOS用のアセンブリをMacでそのまま動かすことはできません。MacでのHelloWorldのサンプル：http://dustin.schultz.io/blog/2010/11/15/mac-os-x-64-bit-assembly-system-calls/

Comment: リンク先では`nasm`を使っていましたが`as`というコマンドもあるようです。どちらを使えばいいのでしょうか?

Comment: `as`はclangのバックエンドなのでclangを使うのと同じです。サンプルはnasm用ですが、少し書き換えればclangでもビルドできます。    https://gist.github.com/h2so5/d429d0aec527482f6209

Comment: `ld`を使う場合は`ld -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11 helloworld -lSystem`でできると思います。

Comment: Hello, worldを表示することができました

Answer (score 1):

cc(1)がld(1)をどのように実行しているかは、

```
cc -v -o helloworld helloworld.s
```

といった感じに`-v`オプションを指定すると調べることができます。(表示された個々のオプションの意味はld(1)のオンラインマニュアルで確認しましょう。)

また、as(1)でアッセンブルした結果のオブジェクト・ファイルは通常、

```
as -arch x86_64 -o helloworld.o helloworld.s
```

と`.o`のファイル名を使用します。